# How to report a no-more-valid-answer to a locked question?

Tags: discussion, historical-lock

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/81650/69537) (last answer on the first page) is linked to a question which exists no more. I wanted to flag it to get it removed but the question is locked and there is no flag option. How can I report it?

Comment: You can't. Historical locks preserve the post *as is*, including all the warts and errors.

Comment: You can report such posts here (on Meta) as you did.